# Is the heat dissipated by a resistor given by $I^2RT$ or $(V^2/R)T$?

Tags: energy, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

Is the heat dissipated by a resistor given by $H = I^2RT$ or $H=(V^2/R)T$? In other words, if the resistance is reduced by a quarter, will the dissipated heat increase or decrease?

The two formulas give different answers for the example values, for current $I=3$, resistance $R=4$, voltage $V=12$ and time $T=1$.

- Case 1: $H = I^2RT$

  - When $R =4$  $H=36$
  - When $R= 1$  $H= 9$

  In the first case the heat just divides by a multiple of 4
- Case 2: $H= (V^2/R)T$

  - When $R=4$  $H=36$
  - When $R =1$  $H=144$

  In the second case the heat just multiplies by a multiple of 4

Comment: If R were 1, you couldn’t still have both I=3 and V=12.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). I have typeset this post, but you should do this yourself in future threads.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are treating resistance and current as independent variables in developing heat in a resistor. They aren't. They are related by Ohms law $I=V/R$. That's why $H=I^{2}Rt$ is equivalent to $H=V^{2}t/R$. If the voltage is fixed, reducing the resistance by a quarter increases the current four fold.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether current or voltage is being held constant. Whichever one is being held constant, the other will change when you change R. Depending on what you choose, power dissipation can go up or down as you increase or decrease R. There are four possible combinations and they are all valid depending on the scenario you choose

Also, those are equation for power dissipation, not heat.

Comment: If you want to nit-pick, the equations are not for power *dissipation* unless you are assuming DC currents and steady state operating conditions. (Resistors emit magic smoke when they generate more heat than they can dissipate!) They are in fact the equations for internal heat *generation* - unless you are talking about circuits where the concept of "an ideal resistor" is irrelevant in any case.

Answer (score 0):

1. the way you write equalities  with current equal temperature equals Voltage is not intelligible.
   it depends if you keep current or voltage constant, since P=I^2*R or P=U^2/R