# Electrical energy is $I^2Rt$, and heat dissipated is also $I^2Rt$?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, electric-circuits, electricity

My book says:

> Let a current $I$ be flowing through a conductor of resistance $R$ for a time $t$, when a source of potential difference $V$ is connected across its ends.

Then, it proceeds to prove that:

> Electrical energy $W$ supplied by the source is$$W = VIt = I^2Rt$$

Then, a few pages later, it is also given (without proper proof, only using some proportionalities) that:

> The amount of heat produced in a wire of resistance $R$ on passing a current $I$ through it is
> $$H = I^2Rt$$

when everything is in SI units.

**My Question**: If/How is this possible? If a source provides some energy, and *all* of it is dissipated as heat, is it of any use?

---

I feel this may be a duplicate, but searching only got me things like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572796/is-the-heat-dissipated-by-a-resistor-given-by-i2rt-or-v2-rt).

Comment: It is correct. A resistor just converts the energy it gets into heat. It is useful as a heater, at least. Note that quite a lot of chemistry and stuff depended upon this, because measuring voltages and currents is a lot more precise than other ways to generate heat energy.

Comment: But when I have other appliances (that don't necessarily give heat as an output)? @naturallyInconsistent

Comment: In that case they are not necessarily modelled as resistors. Maybe they still are, but it would be an approximation of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"If a source provides some energy, and all of it is dissipated as heat, is it of any use?"

Do you not consider electric heaters, (eg fan heaters, convectors) useful?

They consist, essentially, of a length of wire across which we place a potential difference. Once the wire has reached its equilibrium temperature all the electrical energy taken from the source is given out as heat from the wire.

If, though, the wire is moving through a magnetic field, as in an electric motor, a 'back emf' will be induced in it, so that the effective potential difference across the wire will be less than the source emf, so heat given off is less than the energy taken from the source. The rest of the energy taken from the source is available as mechanical work done by the motor spindle.

Comment: I have been introduced to motors and dynamos, but certainly not back emf. Can you direct me to appropriate reading material, or explain it intuitively? Also, is it related to Lenz law (which I'm familiar with)? Thanks!

Comment: When you have relative motion between coil and (electro)magnets in a motor, the system can't help but act as a generator at the same time. Lenz's law shows that the emf generated, magnitude $\mathscr E_B$, opposes the source emf, $\mathscr E$. That's why engineers and many physicists call the generated emf a *back-emf*.  The effective pd responsible for the heating of the wire in the coils of the motor is $\mathscr E-\mathscr E_B$ so $\mathscr EI$ = power input, $\mathscr E_BI$ = mechanical power  output, $(\mathscr E-\mathscr E_B)I$ = heat output.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 3):

The first law of thermodynamics tells us that $$\Delta U=Q-W$$, where U is the internal energy of the system, Q is the heat added to the system, and W is the amount of work done by the system on its surroundings.  In our case, our system is the wire, which presumably has reached steady state, such that its temperature is no longer rising.  So, once steady state has been established, the internal energy of our system is no longer changing ($\Delta U=0$).  The amount of work done by our system on the surroundings is $W=-I^2R\Delta t$, since the surroundings are doing electrical work on our system.  From this, it follows that$$Q=W=-I^2R\Delta t$$This means that, in order to hold the temperature of our system (the wire) constant, we must remove as heat the amount of electrical energy dissipated in the wire.

Answer (score 2):

A key phrase is, "a conductor of *resistance* " All of the electrical power that is dissipated in a resistor is converted to heat. The same is not true of, for example, an electric motor. The amount of power consumed by a motor cannot be calculated as $I^2R$ because the motor is *not a resistor.* The power *can* be calculated as $IV$ where $V$ is the voltage across the motor's terminals though, and in that case, if you perform the right measurements, you'll find that *some* of the electrical power delivered to the motor is converted to heat in the body of the motor itself, but the rest of it becomes *work* done on the motor's output shaft.

Of course, even the mechanical work ultimately will be converted to heat *somewhere,* but the point is, it's somewhere outside of the motor, and we can regard the motor and the machine that it drives as doing something useful with that energy.

Also, consider an electric lamp. Some of the electrical energy delivered to a lamp will raise the temperature of the lamp, but the rest of it will become visible radiation. In this case, you could argue that the visible radiation technically is just another form of heat, but again the point is, the energy is doing something useful (providing us with light to see by) outside of the lamp itself.

Comment: There are things (antennas for example) that obey Ohm's law but do not generate heat. The energy goes somewhere else. But we often model them as resistors.